# MemoryMapped file Access Exception

Tags: c#, io, memory-mapped-files

I am trying to read a huge file (binary\text mixed) using MemoryMap.

However, it comes to a point of my loop iteration that it just gives an access exception ; just it, it doesn't say anything about what kind of exception it is, why it couldn't read, etc. I've been trying to figure out it for a few hours but can't get any conclusion.

Here's the code i am using to read it:

```
                //numOfColors = 6 

 private static void ReadChunksFromLargeFile(int offsetToBegin, string fName, int numOfColors)
    {
        var idx = offsetToBegin;
        int byteSizeForEachColor = (int)new FileInfo(fName).Length/ numOfColors;            

            var buffer = new byte[byteSizeForEachColor];
            using (var mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(fName))
            {
                for(int i=0; i < numOfColors; i++)
                {
                //numOfColors = 6 
                    using (var view = mmf.CreateViewStream(idx, byteSizeForEachColor, MemoryMappedFileAccess.Read))
                    {
                    view.Seek(idx, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        view.Read(buffer, 0, byteSizeForEachColor);
                    var temp = ByteArrayToHexString(buffer);
                    File.WriteAllText($@"C:\test\buffertest{i}.hex", temp);
                    }
                idx += byteSizeForEachColor;
                }
            }    

    }
```

EDIT: offsetToBegin is 937

What i'm trying to do is read huge chunks based on a size i need. However, when it comes to i = 5 it just throws the exception.

The file i'm trying to read is this one: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DsLaNnAOQDyWJ_g4PPNXGCNfbuirs_Ss/view?usp=sharing

Any input is appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: How big is the file? What is `numOfColors`? I am guessing that the file size, minus the offset, should divide equally between the number of colors? Have you tried subtracting the `offsetToBegin` from the `FileInfo.Length` value before dividing by `numOfColors`?

Comment: @SimplyGed i've also tried to start from 0(begin), had the same issue. The file is 39,585,152  bytes. Even starting from 0 i'm having the same exception. Sorry, i forgot to say that numOfColors is 6. I'll add this information to the question.

Comment: It's been a while since I worked with MM IO, but why not create a view of the whole file and seek within that rather than allocate multiple views?

Answer (score 0):

Your calculations are wrong. When you calculate the size of each color you are not taking into account the offset that you don't want. When you call `CreateViewFromStream` and tell it to skip the `offset` it is trying to read too many bytes, causing the `AccessException`.

For example:

- Filesize = 60 bytes
- offset = 2 bytes
- num of colors = 6

Your original calculation would result in:

- byteSizeForEachColor = 10

So your loop will skip the first 2 bytes and then read 10 bytes for each color, but when it comes to the last color it has already gone past the end of the file

- 5 x (10 + 2) = 60
- 6 x (10 + 2) = 72  // The file is only 60 bytes long - it has gone too far

You need to subtract the `offsetToBegin` from the calculated size to ensure it only reads the correct number of bytes.

Using the above values

- bytesizeForEachColor = (60 / 6) - 2 = 8

So it should only read 8 bytes for each color. You need to change your code to:

```
using (var view = mmf.CreateViewStream(idx, byteSizeForEachColor - idx, MemoryMappedFileAccess.Read))
{
    ...
}
```

Now each loop will skip 2 bytes and read 8 - which will not cause it to go beyond the length of the file.